# basic javascript button functionaility (hide/show content)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First off, I am not good at this, i found similar questions with answers but those did not end up in me being able to fix my own problem.

My problem is as follows: a button that when clicked reveals a div with content.
Closest i have gotten was using only html and css, where clicking the button would result in keeping its own div hidden and showing the others (basicly the exact opposite of what i wanted to achieve). After I had done getting my 'feel' back for html/css i started with javascript and rewriting stuff.

Resulting in this: (html)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

 $("#button").click(function (){
    var target = '#' + $(this).data('target');
    $("#hidden-div").slideUp()
    $(target).slideDown()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main" id="main">
    <section class="listview">
    <h1 class="title">List of functions used on the page</h1>
    <ul class ="list" id="list">
        <li>Splash page.
        <button class="btn-list" data-target="splash-div" id="splash-btn">Explanation</button><br>
        <div class="hidden-div" id="splash-div">blablabla</div><br>
        <a class="listlink" href="#splash">Take me there!</a></li>
        <li>Interactive list.
        <button class="btn-list" data-target="list-div" id="list-btn">Explanation</button><br>
        <div class="hidden-div" id="list-div">blablabla</div><br>
        <a class="listlink" href="#list">Take me there!</a></li>
    </ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

EDITTED CODE.

I have tried .css(instead of show), first trying hidden true/false and after content: none/block.

Content none/block is how i got to make it 'work' without using javascript.

Am i missing something obvious? Or am i trying by using the wrong functions?

Comment: You're forgetting the # into jquery $("#splash-btn").button().click(function () {
    $("#splash-div").show();
});

Comment: First of all you've invalid HTML structure.. `<ul>` shouldn't contain `a` and `div` as direct childs.

Comment: @kriekshen , So what do you want exactly.? , `You want to hide a div on click of a button?` or `Hide a dive and show other div with the same class/id.?`

Comment: @Zakaria Acharki how should i structure it in a more 'correct' way then?

Comment: @JithinRajPR all the divs start of hidden. when button is clicked, hide all divs then show the div correspondant to the button.

Comment: @krieksken put all the `a` and `div` inside the `li` tags, that's the proper way. Can I re-arrange it for you with a working function for you.?

Comment: The direct child of `ul` should be `li`..

Comment: It would be helpfull yes, i have changed the a and div tags to be inside the li's.

Comment: Ok just update the question with the new structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your **request** I have updated your **Q** structure and applied a function that is suitable for your situation. **If this is not what you want**, please comment I will restructure it and answer as per your need. Hopes this help.ty!

***UPDATED CODE FOR YOU***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("body").on('click', '.btn-list', function() {
    $(".hidden-div").hide();
    $(this).closest(".hideClass").find(".hidden-div").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main" id="main">
  <section class="listview">
    <h1 class="title">List of functions used on the page</h1>
    <ul class="list" id="list">
      <li class="hideClass">
        <p>Splash page1.</p>
        <button class="btn-list" data-target="#splash-div" id="splash-btn">Show me more</button><br>
        <div class="hidden-div" id="splash-div">blablabla</div>
        <a class="listlink" href="#splash">Take me there!</a>
      </li>
      <li class="hideClass">
        <p>Splash page2.</p>
        <button class="btn-list" data-target="#list-div" id="list-btn">Show me more</button><br>
        <div class="hidden-div" id="list-div">blablabla</div>
        <a class="listlink" href="#list">Take me there!</a>
      </li>
      <li class="hideClass">
        <p>Splash page3.</p>
        <button class="btn-list" data-target="#list-div" id="list-btn">Show me more</button><br>
        <div class="hidden-div" id="list-div">blablabla</div>
        <a class="listlink" href="#list">Take me there!</a>
      </li>
      <li class="hideClass">
        <p>Splash page4.</p>
        <button class="btn-list" data-target="#list-div" id="list-btn">Show me more</button><br>
        <div class="hidden-div" id="list-div">blablabla</div>
        <a class="listlink" href="#list">Take me there!</a>
      </li>
      <li class="hideClass">
       <p>Splash page5.</p>
        <button class="btn-list" data-target="#list-div" id="list-btn">Show me more</button><br>
        <div class="hidden-div" id="list-div">blablabla</div>
        <a class="listlink" href="#list">Take me there!</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for answering my question. I am sure that your answer will work how I wanted it to work. Only the button does not seem to be clickable?

Comment: @krieksken check out the snippet it's working fine.?

Comment: yes in snippet the button seems to be working, I changed your function so it hides the 'blablabla' instead of the list item. other then that i did not change anything

Comment: it will not work like that. I will change the function for you. Structure of code is same na.?

Comment: @krieksken I have updated the answer. Please check if it's what you wanted.? and if it's working please mark as answer.ty

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, should solve your problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#splash-btn").click(function() {
    $("#splash-div").show();
  });
  
  $("#list-btn").click(function() {
    $("#list-div").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden-div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main" id="main">
  <section class="listview">
    <h1 class="title">List of functions used on the page</h1>
    <ul class="list" id="list">
      <li>Splash page.</li>
      <button class="btn-list" id="splash-btn">Show me more</button><br>
      <div class="hidden-div" id="splash-div">blablabla</div>
      <button class="btn-list" id="list-btn">Show me more</button><br>
      <div class="hidden-div" id="list-div">blablabla</div>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").on('click',function() {
    debugger;
    var selecteddiv = $(this).attr("id") + '-div';
    $("#"+selecteddiv).toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden-div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main" id="main">
  <section class="listview">
    <h1 class="title">List of functions used on the page</h1>
    <ul class="list" id="list">
      <li>Splash page.</li>
      <button class="btn-list" id="splash">Show / Hide</button><br>
      <div class="hidden-div" id="splash-div">blablabla</div>
      <button class="btn-list" id="list">Show / Hide</button><br>
      <div class="hidden-div" id="list-div">sdfsdfsdfsdf</div>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```